# What does offset mean in Dashing?

Tags: graphics

What exactly does "offset" mean for a graphics directive of the form `Dashing[{d1,d2},offset]`?

That is, exactly what is offset from what where?

The Documentation Center seems to take the meaning for granted, except for the single example below, which still does not articulate for me what is offset how where.

```
   Table[Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}], Dashing[{.1, .05}, o], Red, 
      Opacity[.5], Thickness[.05], Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}]}], 
     {o, {-0.05, 0, 0.05}}]
```

Does the offset represent the fraction of the total image width by which the first dash from the first of the two ends of the line is pushed away from that first end?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: From the documentation, "offset is specified as a fraction of the total width of the graph, and it may be positive or negative. If offset is not specified, it is 0."

Comment: @BobHanlon: Yes, that says how offset is specified, but it does not say what it *means*!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

The `offset` is the movement of the `dash`(but need to $\mod (r1+r2)$). Just like a `TranslationTransform[offset]` or similar with `RotateLeft`.

[image]

```
r1 = 2/3;
r2 = 1/3;
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], Dashing[{r1, r2}, offset], 
   Opacity[.3], Thickness[.25], Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-.2, .2}}], {offset, 0, r1 + r2}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

**Original**

A long comment.

- For arbitrary positive or negative `offset`, the final `offset` is the remainder on division of `r1+r2` by `offset`. For example, `offset=9`, `r1 = .1;r2 = .05;`,then the final `offset` is

```
r1 = .1;
r2 = .05;
offset=9;
Mod[offset,r1+r2,0]
( * 0.15 *)
```

We can see they are the same in the animation.

```
r1 = .1;
r2 = .05;
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 π}, 
   PlotStyle -> Dashing[{r1, r2}, offset]], 
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 π}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.2], Red, Thickness[.03], 
     Dashing[{r1, r2}, Mod[offset, r1 + r2, 0]]}]], {offset, 0, 
  2 (r1 + r2)}, ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

- If we set `{r1,r2},offset`, then `{r2,r1},r2+offset` is the complement.

[image]

```
r1 = .1;
r2 = .05;
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 π}, 
   PlotStyle -> Dashing[{r1, r2}, offset]], 
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3 π}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.2], Red, Thickness[.03], 
     Dashing[{r2, r1}, r2 + offset]}]], {offset, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

- But I still don't understand the meaning of the size of `r1=2/3` and `r2=1/3` etc. The difference results as below still confuse me.

```
r1 = 2/3;
r2 = 1/3;
offset = 0;
{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashing[{r1, r2}, offset]}], 
  Plot[x, {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashing[{r1, r2}, offset]}], 
  Plot[0, {x, 0, 3}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashing[{r1, r2}, offset]}]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

Comment: ``r1`` and ``r2`` are specified in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dashing.html) as _a fraction of the total width of the graph._ And this is exactly what they are. Try with ``r1 = r2 = .1`` and [compare plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4rYJ.png) of $0$ and $\sin x$. There are exactly 5 red and 5 blank patches in the straight line (10 in total, therefore each with length 0.1). And the lengths of the patches are the same in $\sin x$, but there is more of them because the curve is longer in total. Maybe you can add this to your answer to make it complete :-)

Comment: @Domen Thanks, Maybe I can draw another animate to illustrate this later.

Comment: @Domen But `Sin[x]` have `11` parts. I don't understand it. `r1 = .1;
r2 = .1;
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Opacity[.2], Red, Thickness[.01], 
   Dashing[{r1, r2}, 0]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Then the in-comment reply, "Yes, that is correct," to my question "Does the offset represent the fraction of the total image width by which the first dash from the first of the two ends of the line is pushed away from that first end?" is wrong! The offset pushes the dash not away from, but toward the beginning of the line, according to the Edit in this answer. Which all goes to show why an actual explanation of "offset" is sadly missing, and needed, in the Documentation Center!